# AndroidX multiple instances of Preferences

Tags: android, settings, androidx

How can I keep multiple sets of Preferences using the AndroidX Perference library?
For example, the user can choose different profiles which have different values over the same set of settings:

Global preferences:

- Selected profile: foo
- Other settings: etc

Profile 1:

- Name: foo
- Setting: Bar

Profile 2:

- Name: bar
- Setting: Hello

etc

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

- Use [`Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) with different names for different profiles. `PreferenceManager` has a [`setDefaultValues`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) method that also takes a name in that case. The downside of this approach is that a settings screen will still use the default shared prefs, and not the ones for whatever profile is selected.
- Make your own shared prefs wrapper that extends [`PreferenceDataStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceDataStore) and implements all the methods. Then call [`PreferenceManager.setPreferenceDataStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#setPreferenceDataStore(androidx.preference.PreferenceDataStore)) whenever the profile is changed. A settings screen will show the correct values with this approach. Internally, your wrapper can either use a database to store the values, or use the default shared prefs, appending a different prefix for different profiles.

I haven't tried either but I believe it could work.